# how to use if else statement in python to bin a variable

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

Hi I have a variable 'age' in my data and i want to bin it in python and save it into a new variable. something like this"

```
data['new_age']= if data['age'] <= 16 then 'young'
                 if data['age'] > 16 & data['age'] <= 35 then 'adult'
                 else 'old' end
```

how can i do this with a pandas data frame?

Comment: check out pd.cut() - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 2):

```
def new_age(r):
    if r['age']<=16:
        return 'young'
    if r['age'] <=35
        return 'adult'
    return 'old'

df['new_age'] = df.apply(lambda x: new_age(x),axis = 1)
```

completely disagree with your age dividing, 35 is a young adult

Answer (score 1):

Besides the @trigonom classic pythonic solution (explicitly answering your question), other options include:

Using `numpy.select`:

```
df['new_age'] = np.select([df.age.lt(16), (df.age.gt(16)) & (df.age.le(35))], ['young','adult'], 'old')
```

Or `pd.cut` (as pointed out by @Mike Tomaino):

```
df['new_age'] = pd.cut(df.age, [0, 16, 35, np.inf], labels=['young', 'adult', 'old'])
```